# Explain [:0] in Python

Tags: python

Ok, so before I get flamed for not RTFM, I understand that [:0] in my case of:

```
s ="itsastring"
newS= []
newS[:0] = s
```

ends up converting s to a list through slicing.  This is my end goal, but coming from a Java background, I don't fully understand the "0" part in "[:0] and syntactically why it's placed there (I know it roughly means increase by 0).  Finally, how does Python know that I want to have each char of s be an element based on this syntax?  I want to understand it so I can remember it more clearly.

Comment: By the way the list you are trying to slice "newS" does not have any value so how in world you that think that something will get assigned to s?

Comment: [:0] does not mean "increase by zero."  It means "slice this iterable from its beginning (the implicit 0 on the left side of the colon) to position 0 (the explicit 0 on the right side of the colon)."  Slicing a string with [:0] will return the empty string; slicing a list that way will return the empty list.

Answer (score 2):

If *S* and *T* are sequences, `S[a:b] = T` will replace the subsequence from index *a* to *b-1* of *S* by the elements of *T*.
If `a == b`, it will act as a simple insertion.
And `S[:0]` is the same thing as `S[0:0]` : so it's a simple insertion at the front.

```
s = [11,22,33,44,55,66,77]
s[3:3] = [1,2,3] # insertion at position 3
print( s )

s = [11,22,33,44,55,66,77]
s[3:4] = [1,2,3] # deletion of element at position 3, and then insertion 
print( s )

s = [11,22,33,44,55,66,77]
s[3:6] = [1,2,3] # deletion of elements from position 3 to 5, and then insertion 
print( s )

s = [11,22,33,44,55,66,77]
s[:] = [1,2,3] # deletion of all elements, and then insertion : whole replacement 
print( s )
```

output:

```
[11, 22, 33, 1, 2, 3, 44, 55, 66, 77]
[11, 22, 33, 1, 2, 3, 55, 66, 77]
[11, 22, 33, 1, 2, 3, 77]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you.  Knowing now that [:0] is short for [0:0] helps a lot in understanding the syntax now.  I was thinking "Why is the 0 at the end there?"  It didn't make sense to me as that's usually the end index.  Pointing out that [:0] short for [0:0] clears things up a lot.  I've tried searching on Stack and Google for "python [:0]" but nothing relevant turns up, and I just receive info on graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps:

```
s ="itsastring"

#if you add any variable in left side then python will start slicing from there
#and slice to one less than last index assigned on right side
newS = s[:]
```

Answer (score 0):

So the `[:0]` means slice the string from the beggining to the `0` (or again the first) element in the `s` string and the result is nothing. By default the slicing is done from the first element to the last or `print(s[0:])` is the same as `print(s)`.

I suggest you try a loop through the whole string like this:

```
s = [x for x in "itsastring"]
print(s)

# result
['i', 't', 's', 'a', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

Comment: Thank you.  Knowing now that [:0] is short for [0:0] helps a lot in understanding the syntax now.  I was thinking why is the 0 at the end there, because it didn't make sense to me as that using the end index.  Pointing out that its short for [0:0] clears things up a lot.  I've tried searching on Stack and Google for [:0] but nothing relevant turns up, or I just receive info on graphs.